# jQuery-UI's Sortable function moves div unnecessarily

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have been working with jquery-ui's sortable demo for a while.

On looking closely, I found that it nudges the divs slightly.

Here's an online demo : http://jsbin.com/ijusu3

Try moving the the center one to the left, then you can see the right ones nudging about 2 pixels to the left.

I would like to know why. This has been messing up the rest of my functionality.

PS: If jsbin doesnt show the code, here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Portlets</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .container { width: 788px; height: 405px; }
    .column { width: 78px; height:405px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;}
    .portlet { width: 78px; height: 10px; display: block; position:relative; }  
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $(".column").sortable({
            connectWith: '.column',
            helper:'original'
        });

        $(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all");

        $(".column").disableSelection();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" class="container">

    <div id="col-0" class="column">

        <div class="portlet" id="feeds">
            <div class="portlet-content"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet" id="news">
            <div class="portlet-content"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="col-1" class="column">

        <div class="portlet" id="shopping">
            <div class="portlet-content"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="col-2" class="column">

        <div class="portlet" id="links">
            <div class="portlet-content"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet" id="images">
            <div class="portlet-content"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is very simple really (though I cannot be sure if this is actually the reason until I see your CSS).

When you add the `ui-widget` class to those `div`s, you're also adding a 1px wide border. The border takes up one pixels on either side of those `div` **in addition** to the 78px you defined as their width, thus their actual width is 80px.

This, combined with the fact that you've specified a 78px width for the columns, means that the columns are too narrow for their content, thus when the last element is removed the column reverts back from 80px to 78px.

I had to modify your [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/ijusu3/2/) to work with jQuery and jQuery UI, so the CSS isn't the same as the one you're using, thus I might be wrong about this. Changing the column width to 80px stopped the columns from shifting around.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining how ui-widget works. This seems to solve the problem in my demo code. Is there a way that I can see the code you had for jsbin ?

Comment: @Hrishikesh It's right there - the links in the answer, and you can press the "Edit" button that appears in the top right hand corner